# Invalid product_id error when requesting a Ride Estimate

Tags: uber-api

I am developing for the Uber API using the Sandbox environment and so far it has worked great.

However now I'm suddently getting errors for seemingly perfectly reasonable requests using the Ride Request Estimate API call (`estimateRide` API call in the [Java Uber Rides SDK](https://github.com/uber/rides-java-sdk)), and am getting this error:

```
not_found 
Invalid product_id
com.uber.sdk.rides.client.error.ApiException: 404 Not Found
Caused by: retrofit.RetrofitError: 404 Not Found
```

The requests are for example from 51.49661, -0.143597 or 51.49710, -0.14348 (and productName uberX). Just before performing the actual Ride Request Estimate API call, I am using the `getProducts` API call to get the available Products for the given coordinates (which are identical to the one I am using for the Ride Request Estimate), and then filtering to pick the one the user has requested (e.g. uberX).

As I said, 99% of the time everything works great, but now suddenly I started getting these errors, and only for specific accounts I'm testing with.

What I am doing wrong? I can provide more details if needed.

[EDIT] The problem has reappared just now (2016-04-06 17:42:50 UTC). Example lat/lon that caused the error: 51.5038652, -0.2714952. Until this time, the endpoint has worked perfectly.

Comment: Hey Shortcut, has the issue resolved itself? I tried recreating it with the coordinates you provided and I did not receive a 404.

If its still occurring, could you give me the exact parameters you were making requests with so I can attempt to recreate?

Comment: Hi, the issue has resolved itself, yes. This appears has happened at least 3-4 times so far - it would occur during for example half an hour or so, then it would just suddenly stop. Every other endpoint would work fine, except the Ride Request Estimate - for example getProducts works just fine. I will post the exact parameters the next time it occurs. Note that it occurs only for one of the users I'm testing with, it does NOT occur for example at the same time with any another user (it's not a specific user, each time it's a random one). I will report when the issue happens again. Thanks!

Comment: @RichardArtoul getting it again just now, from lat 51.49710999999999 lon -0.14348000000001093 to lat 51.49346160888672 lon -0.27474403381347656 for uberX productId 3cb90303-3869-4701-a8fd-92efba468a94 error is ClientError(not_found): Invalid product_id

Comment: @RichardArtoul the previous error was received at 2016-04-08 08:54:26 UTC - now it disappeared (2016-04-08 08:58:00 UTC) - same request works again, both from the server and from the cURL. Sadly I tried to do the two cURL requests as fast as I could but the request started working again too quickly for me to enter all the correct parameters.

Comment: Hi, is there a chance that the issue is happening because the Uber user that I am testing with (internally using our app) is on a separate ride using the Uber app? I have correlated the times and it seems that the latest times I am getting the error match with the times I am on a ride using the Uber app.

Comment: Hey Shortcut,

Thanks for providing so much detail. I was able to reproduce the issue. It indeed only seems to occur when you try to request an estimate and the user is already on a request.

I'm gonna file it as a bug and see if we can get it fixed! Thanks again!

Best,
   Richie

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When in non-sandbox (Production) mode, you cannot fetch trip estimates if the user is currently on a ride.

The `404 NotFound` error you reported was a bug in the API that has been fixed. We still do not allow you to query for trip estimates if there is an ongoing trip, but we have fixed the error response to be more accurate. Now, you should see a `403 Forbidden` error, with `code: current_trip_exists` and the `message: Trip estimates not allowed while the user is currently on a trip.`